# How to get “Visitors Flow” data from Google Analytics GAPI API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics there is a verry nice "visitor flow" page that clearly contains and keeps track of what path a visitor has taken on the site. Is it possible to get that data from the API? I know that you can use "custom variables" to give the users a unique ID and i do that already but what im after is to be able to use the data already collected without custom variables. I have got the following at the moment:

```
$ga->requestReportData(56786432, array('networkLocation', 'date', 'hour', 'nextPagePath', 'previousPagePath'), array('avgTimeOnSite', 'visits','pageviews'), array('-date', '-hour'), null, null, null, 1, 100);
```

This gives me visit "sessions" with date and hour and i think this is a start but how to continue from here? Is it possible?

EDIT
I have now added nextPagePath and previousPagePath as new dimentions and pageviews as a metric. This gives somewhat of the path that the visitor went through the site. If the visitor went the path **A->B->C->exit** this gives me the result:

```
pageviews:1 previous:(entrence) next: :A
pageviews:1 previous:B next: :C
pageviews:1 previous:A next: :B
```

The above result is indeed correct but if the visitor went backwards and forwards on the site multiple times crossing from A->B and A->C multiple times its not possible for me to track when he went to B and when he went to C

```
pageviews:1 previous:(entrence) next: :A
pageviews:2 previous:A next: :C
pageviews:5 previous:A next: :B
pageviews:2 previous:C next: :A
pageviews4 previous:B next: :C
```

If its possible i need to get a result for each new page the visitor got to in the right order.

I saw this question already but it didnt get me any closer to my answer: [Get Google Analytics "Visitors Flow" data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502062/get-google-analytics-visitors-flow-data-from-api)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently facing [a similar problem using the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553782/how-to-extract-engagement-flow-data-using-google-analytics-reporting-api) and I ran across both your question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502062/get-google-analytics-visitors-flow-data-from-api). You can certainly [get the flow data out of the Google Analytics Reporting API and run any kind of analysis on it you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566884/564709). The challenge is that you will likely have to paginate through the results using one of the [core reporting libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) to access all of the results.

Regarding your question about tracking the back/forward navigation movements, that might be good to ask as a separate question. If its possible, you will probably have to add some custom javascript on your page using the [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) package somehow, but I'm not an expert on how to do that.

Note: I'm no lawyer, but I think it may be against the [Google Analytics Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) to try and track individual users in your application. If I am wrong, that would be delightful and I would like to start doing it myself!