# How to extract engagement flow data using google analytics reporting api

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I am building an Android app that uses Google Analytics to record various Events and Screens throughout the app. The Engagement Flow dashboard is quite striking but I'd like to export the data and play with it on my own. How can I write my app so that I can extract the data that is used in the Engagement Flow dashboard using the [Google Core Reporting API](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)?

Currently, I am using [sendEvent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events) and [sendView](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens) to track Events and Screens respectively in the Engagement Flow. I'm guessing my approach is working because the report works correctly in the Google Analytics UI, but I can't get the data out using the Core Reporting API for Android. I am fairly confident this is doable because I've been able to access the data using the [query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) for our website with the `ga:previousPagePath` and `ga:pagePath` dimensions (see screenshot below), but the same thing does not work for the Android SDK. I can get some data out using an undocumented `ga:screenName` dimension, but the corresponding `ga:previousScreenName` (and any permutation thereof) does not exist. Thoughts?

[image]

For what its worth, others have had similar questions in case its useful:

- [How to get “Visitors Flow” data from Google Analytics GAPI API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185260/how-to-get-visitors-flow-data-from-google-analytics-gapi-api)
- [Get Google Analytics "Visitors Flow" data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502062/get-google-analytics-visitors-flow-data-from-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google-Analytics, as of now this feature is not available.

Comment: Can you please share the documentation link that you are referencing?

Comment: This was not from documentation but from speaking with them personally. At the time I looked extensively through the docs and didn't find that info there -- but did get it from talking to them. Which is why I posted it here, for others to see. Sorry I don't have a reference!