# Google Analytics Engagement Report API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does Google Analytics Reporting API support calls to get the user engagement report data (as present in the Analytics website)

[image: GA-EngagementReporting]

I searched but could not get any tangible information. I am not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553782/how-to-extract-engagement-flow-data-using-google-analytics-reporting-api) is same as what I am looking for.

Can someone please point me to some tangible info regarding this.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?  I too would like to simulate this chart.

Comment: @Schenkel, nope. not yet. I was spiking something and needed that info. When actual dev starts I would have to dig deeper. Shall update if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant source for all "can I query this from the API"-questions is the "[Dimensions and Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)" from the Google Analytics Documentation.

The closest thing to what you want is [ga:sessionDurationBucket](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessiondurationbucket). However this dimension (it looks like a metric/number but is actually a string and a dimension) reports in second increments, whereas the report in the GA interface reports in 30 second increments. So if you query this from the api you would have to do the grouping into larger increments yourself.