# How to access Behavior Flow data? (on a Application Google Analytics Account.)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to load **behavior flow** data from GA through Analytics API. I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502062/get-google-analytics-visitors-flow-data-from-api) that I may do it using `ga:previousPagePath` and `ga:pagePath` dimensions. However in my case these dimensions are empty (not sure whether it's so due to mobile app, or due to some app bugs).
Generally I rely on `ga:screenName`. However there is no field `ga:previousScreenName`, so I can't do that the same way.

Is there any way to access behavior flow data in this case?

I see there is a flow diagram in *Behavior* -> *Behavior Flow*. Is it possible to access data this one is based on?

Answer (score 2):

If you normally use `ga:screenname` that is because you have a application Google Analytics application.  `ga:previousPagePath` and `ga:pagePath` are used for web Google Analytics accounts.  There will be no data in those metadata items for an application Google Analytics account.

As you have already noticed there is no flow data for Application Google analytics accounts.   You are limited to these [meta data items](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=app_tracking).

You could add this as a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list).